# How to show employees who were absent (did not clock in) in Google Sheets with Google Form data?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, google-forms

I made a Google Form for employees to use to clock in and out each day. The data is going to a Google Sheet, which is turned into a pivot table and all is well except for how to view which employees did not clock in on a specific day. Ideally, I want a list of absent employees per day/employees who did not clock in/out on a certain day.

The Google Form has employees select their name from a drop down menu and select clock in or clock out. The data goes to a Google Sheet, which I have made a data processed tab from, to make a pivot table from. The list of absent employees does not need to be within pivot table, it can be a seperate tab. If it is possible to have absent employees listed somehow in the pivot table, that's great. Not a big deal if not.

Right now, I am manually going in and selecting employees who clocked in/out on a particular date, adding that to its own column, and comparing that column with the master employee list. Is there an automated way to do this? I am familiar with comparing two columns, but can't figure out how to sort employees based on the date they clocked in/out into one column to then compare it to another one (unless I manually create column at end of work day). Thank you!!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1v5ssyIaW0fUdIBTKTr6FNZIzV1WNilqN/view?usp=sharing This is the raw data from Google From

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1axWe_nPSTvIPM2RvIz7AQZE_NSJmIEdQ/view?usp=sharing This is processed data which fills pivot table

https://drive.google.com/file/d/13rBxzJ5RtnYc-vo3RzocMrSwtMy9kbaB/view?usp=sharing This is pivot table

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] as you shouldn't link to files. But instead show us your data/code/formulas within your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way